# Magento - 500 internal server error- custom script for importing color

Tags: php, magento

I have a script somewhat like this

```
$csv_array  = array();
    while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
        $csv_array[trim($row[0])] = trim($row[1]);
    }

     $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute("color");

    $csv_array = array_chunk($csv_array, 100, true);

    foreach($csv_array as $key => $chunk_arr) {

        foreach ($chunk_arr as $sku => $color) {
    unset($product);
    $color_id = null;

            //check sku is not empty
            if (empty($sku) && !isset($sku)) {
                continue;
            }


            //check if sku exists in Magento
            $product = $productModel->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);


            if (!$product) {
                echo $sku . 'not found';
                continue;
            }

            //Set vendor item id to product object
            try {

                if ($attr->usesSource()) {
                    $color_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId($color);
                }

                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('color' => $color_id), $storeId);

                Mage::log($sku, null, 'import.log');

                echo 'Sku ' . $sku . ' updated!!!!<br/>';

            } catch (Exception $e) {

                echo 'Sku ' . $sku . ' not updated!!!!<br/>';
            }

        }
        unset($chunk_arr);
    }
```

My script break after 100 times execution of loop and throws 500 server internal error. Please help me if you have any suggestion.
I have tried everything such as memory limit, max execution time, upload file size, post max size and all.

Comment: What does the error log say? You should have some kind of message in `MAGEDIR/var/log/system.log`, `MAGEDIR/var/log/exception.log`, or in the generic PHP error log (often combined with the apache error log). You would also be better off doing this from the command line.

Comment: There are no entries in system.log or any other log for this..Also checked apache error log but no luck.

Comment: Can you ssh into the server and run in from the command-line? Hopefully will output the error directly to the console.

Comment: Running it through curl. Since code is run with the controller. Cannot hit script directly.